# annotation while hovering over saved matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

The amount of data that I need to plot is above 30k points. I'm aware that the hover over functionality is possible for an active graph. But is it possible to display the value of a particular data point when hovered over on saved matplotlib plots?

Are there any other interactive plotters that offer such a functionality for saved plots?

Comment: which file format is the file saved, only SVG can have an interaction, you can use D3 to visualize your data

Comment: Somehow you'll need to save the data together with the plot. A limited solution is reading in the image, and display it via `imshow(....extent=[x0, x1, y0, y1])`. If x0 etc are correctly set, this will show the coordinates in the statusbar while hovering. This will show the positions independent whether a scatter dot is under the cursor.  The best solution would be to save the data instead of the image and recreate the plot.

Comment: You might need to switch to `plotly` or `bokeh` for standalone plot with interactions, they are saved as html format.

Comment: @rioV8 was saved in PNG.